# Iterate links from selenium into bs4 and print stripped strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

Intent:

1.Access the main page for http://blogdobg.com.br/ with Selenium.

2.Identify the article links

3.Insert each link into bs4 and pull the text

Problem:
I can get as far as printing all the links or moving a single link into bs4
for parsing and printing. My attempts at reading each link ended in the same link iterated many times.

I just started learning myself two days ago, so any pointers would be appreciated.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from lxml import html
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def read (html):
    html = browser.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
    for string in soup.article.stripped_strings:
            print(repr(string))

path_to_chromedriver = '/Users/yakir/chromedriver' 
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_chromedriver)

url = 'http://blogdobg.com.br/'
browser.get(url)

articles = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("""//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "entry-title", " " ))]//a""")

#get all the links
for link in articles:
    link.get_attribute("href")

#Attempt to print striped string from each link's landing page
for link in articles:
        read(link.get_attribute("href"))

##method for getting one link to work all the way through (currently commented out)
#article1 = articles[1].get_attribute("href")
#browser.get(article1)
#read(article1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your function `read()` has `html` parameter while you define `html` variable directly inside this function. This make no sense: your argument will be ignored anyway and `BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")` will get value from `html = browser.page_source`, but not from argument `html`

Another issue: you won't get **all links** with

```
for link in articles:
    link.get_attribute("href")
```

You should use `list` and append values on each iteration:

```
link_list = []
for link in articles:
    link_list.append(link.get_attribute("href"))
```

Then you can use your links like:

```
for link in link_list:
    r = requests.get(link)
    ...
    # do whatever you want to do with response
```